# Linux: Setting up permissions on a directory, so that one user has rwx on everything, while everyone else only has rwx on own files

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-sharing

I want to create a directory, in which the following rules apply:

- One user can see every file in there, open and edit it
- Other users can put new files there
- Other users can see, open and edit their own files (that they created themselves)
- Except that one user, nobody should ever see anything from anyone else
- Preventing flooding is not a concern

Maybe I'm going at this wrong though...
What I need, irl, is a place where many people can put their documents for review by that one person, while they definitely must not be able to copy stuff from others. Think school, where you can upload homework for the teacher.

My setup is one central linux server with Samba as a DC and filer, and many windows PCs in its domain.

Any ideas on how to solve this without huge setup are welcome, as long as the result is accessible over Samba.

Comment: Why not use a folder per user ?

Comment: Using one folder per person is not feasible, because The one person seeing everything wants to see it grouped by Task, if any.